# Maintain navbar with full page background

Tags: background, navbar

I've added the following to css in hopes of creating a full page background:

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

I also have the following navbar in HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li class="active">
     <a href="home.html">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="page1.html">...</a></li>
   <li><a href="page2.html">...</a></li>
   <li><a href="page3.html">...</a></li>
</ul>
```

The navbar seems to disappear once the background is added. Is there a way to put the navbar in front of the background?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index
'#bg' could have a -1 as z-index, so it's not clickable.

It's not common to use img-tags for background-images instead you should use background-image: url(...) in css: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that's the path I need to take. Thanks for your help!